# WPF C# Animating a Thumb

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need help correcting either my thumb drag or my animation after the dragging. The steps I basically want is:

1. user left-clicks on the scroll handle and drags handle+image
   horizontally across the window.
2. the handle+image will either snap to the left window edge, or the handle
   will snap to the right window edge with the image hidden to the
   right
3. if the user release the left click while dragging, the
   handle+image will continue on the direction its going to either the
   left or right window edge and snaps to that, c.f. #2

Now, upon loading, it is working as I want, but for the subsequent drags, the thumb dragging visibility is gone.  It just jumps to where I release the left click and continue the snapping animation from there.

I've tried various workarounds, to the best of my ability, but nothing seems to be the solution.  Minimal code is as below.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TouchSample.MainWindow"
        Name="Window_TouchSample"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TouchSample"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" 
    Height="600" Width="600"
    xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:TouchSample">
    <Grid Name="Grid_TouchableThing">
        <custom:TouchableThing />
    </Grid> 
</Window>
```

TouchableThing.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="TouchSample.TouchableThing"
        Name="Scroll_UserControl"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TouchSample"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="600">
    <Canvas x:Name="Scroll_Canvas">

        <Thumb Name="Scroll_thumb" 
               Canvas.Left="20" 
               Canvas.Top="120" 
               Canvas.ZIndex="3"  
               DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta"
               PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="Scroll_thumb_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
            <Thumb.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Name="Scroll_thumb_StackPanel" 
                                Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Border Name="Scroll_thumb_StackPanel_Border" Background="Black" Padding="1">
                            <TextBlock Name="Scroll_thumb_StackPanel_Border_TextBlock" 
                                       Text="Scroll" 
                                       Background="Silver" 
                                       TextAlignment="Center" 
                                       MouseLeftButtonDown="TextBlock_MouseLeftButtonDown"
                                       >
                                <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                                </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Border>
                        <Button Background="Yellow" Padding="1">
                            <Image Name="Scroll_thumb_StackPanel_Button_Image" Source="Assets/long-ancient-scroll-4499037_x4.jpg" />
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Thumb.Template>
        </Thumb>

    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

TouchableThing.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

namespace TouchSample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for TouchableThing.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class TouchableThing : UserControl
    {
        private double toLeftValue = 0;
        private double toRightValue = 550; // will get overwritten in OnWindowSizeChanged
        private bool isGoingLeft = false;
        private bool isGoingRight = false;
        private double lastDiffX;

        public TouchableThing()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.SizeChanged += OnWindowSizeChanged;            
        }

        private void OnWindowSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();

            //Console.WriteLine("sender: " + sender.ToString());
            //Console.WriteLine("sender.GetType(): " + sender.GetType().ToString());
            //Console.WriteLine("e: " + e.ToString());

            toRightValue = e.NewSize.Width;

            var aBorder = VisualHierarchyHelper.FindChild<Border>(Scroll_thumb, "Scroll_thumb_StackPanel_Border");

            if (aBorder != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("aBorder.ActualWidth: " + aBorder.ActualWidth.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("aBorder.RenderSize.Height: " + aBorder.RenderSize.Height.ToString());
                toRightValue -= aBorder.ActualWidth;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("toRightValue=" + toRightValue.ToString());
        }

        // https://wpf.2000things.com/2012/12/19/715-using-the-thumb-control-to-drag-objects-on-a-canvas/
        private void Thumb_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            //UIElement thumb = e.Source as UIElement;
            UIElement thumb = sender as UIElement;

            double xChange = Canvas.GetLeft(thumb) + e.HorizontalChange;

            if(xChange >= toLeftValue && xChange <= toRightValue)
            {
                Canvas.SetLeft(thumb, xChange);
                //Canvas.SetTop(thumb, Canvas.GetTop(thumb) + e.VerticalChange);

                //Console.WriteLine("e.HorizontalChange=" + e.HorizontalChange);
                if (e.HorizontalChange > 0)
                {
                    isGoingLeft = false;
                    isGoingRight = true;
                }
                else if (e.HorizontalChange < 0)
                {
                    isGoingLeft = true;
                    isGoingRight = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    isGoingLeft = false;
                    isGoingRight = false;
                }

                lastDiffX = xChange;
            }
        }

        private void goLeft(UIElement theUIElement, double fromX)
        {
            DoubleAnimation goLeftAnim = new DoubleAnimation();

            goLeftAnim.From = fromX;
            goLeftAnim.To = toLeftValue;
            goLeftAnim.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

            theUIElement.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, goLeftAnim);
        }

        private void goRight(UIElement theUIElement, double fromX)
        {
            DoubleAnimation goRightAnim = new DoubleAnimation();

            goRightAnim.From = fromX;
            goRightAnim.To = toRightValue;
            goRightAnim.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

            theUIElement.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, goRightAnim);
        }

        private void TextBlock_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBlock aTextBlock = sender as TextBlock;

            //Console.WriteLine("TextBlock_MouseLeftButtonDown: Changing TextBlock Background colour to Gray");
            aTextBlock.Background = Brushes.Gray;
        }

        private void Scroll_thumb_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var aTextBlock = VisualHierarchyHelper.FindChild<TextBlock>(Scroll_thumb, "Scroll_thumb_StackPanel_Border_TextBlock");

            if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released && aTextBlock != null)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Scroll_thumb_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp: Changing TextBlock Background colour to Silver");
                //Console.WriteLine("  found aTextBlock");
                aTextBlock.Background = Brushes.Silver;
            }

            if (isGoingLeft)
                goLeft(Scroll_thumb, lastDiffX);
            else if (isGoingRight)
                goRight(Scroll_thumb, lastDiffX);

        }

    }
}
```

I'm just starting with WPF with just a year's experience on C# and WinForms, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Sryn

Answer (score 0):

I asked this same question on MSDN and a moderator there, Yohann Lu, gave a working code for my requirements.  S/He mentioned that I needed to 'clear the animation' by using this code

```
theUIElement.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, null);
```

The thread containing the complete code is at the link below

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/863c85e5-f372-4439-b3dc-f37623665e3a/c-animating-a-thumb?forum=wpf

Thank you Yohann and to anybody who attempted this.

Sryn